# Add css animation before deleting array item

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I would like to do a css animation before deleting an item from my data table. The deletion of an element is triggered by an event `@click`. So I'd like to see first what my animation does (class `delete_animation`) and only after delete the element.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
   addedId: null,
  array: [
     { id: 1, text: "lorem ipsum" },
      { id: 2, text: "lorem ipsum" },
    ]
  },
  methods: {
   add() {
     this.addedId = this.array[this.array.length - 1].id + 1;
      this.array.push({ id: this.addedId, text: "lorem ipsum"} );
    },
    remove(item, index) {
      this.array.splice(index, 1);
      this.addedId = null;
      // ???
    }
  }
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.add_animation {
  animation: addItem 1s;
}

@keyframes addItem {
  0% {
    background-color: green;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
.deleted_animation {
  animation: deleteItem 1s;
}
@keyframes deleteItem {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <table>
    <tr v-for="(index, item) in array" :key="item.id" :class="addedId == item.id ? 'add_animation' : ''">
      <td>{{ item.text }}</td>
      <td> <button type="button" @click="remove(item, index)">remove</button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <button type="button" @click="add()">Add</button>
</div>
```

I would simply like to do the opposite of what the "add" button does. However, I do not see how to handle events to wait for the animation to display. I think i need to trigger click once my animation was displayed, but i don't know how...

Thanks !

Comment: Check out Transitions: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html. You would extract that piece into it's own component. Then the component is in charge of it's animations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure,but as i understood,you want to animate the deletion of an item in array using vue.js.

Everything is simple with vue.js so please see [Vue.js Transitions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html)

I made a simple example for you,animating items when you delete them.It may help you.

[See it in action here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/cuj25L6u/)

**The "html" part**

```
<div id="app">
  <transition-group name="fade">
      <div v-for="(todo,index) in todos" :key="todo.text" @click="deleteItem(index)">
        {{ todo.text}}
      </div>
  </transition-group>
</div>
```

**The javascript part**

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    todos: [
      { text: "Learn JavaScript", done: false },
      { text: "Learn Vue", done: false },
      { text: "Play around in JSFiddle", done: true },
      { text: "Build something awesome", done: true }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
        deleteItem(index) {
        this.todos.splice(index, 1);
    }
  }
})
```

**The css part**

```
.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 1s;
}

.fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `<transition-group>` element around your list, and write your transitions as CSS transitions and Vue.js will take care of setting the correct CSS classes keeping the element there while the exit transition is running. No need to change your logic. For the exact details, check the "List Transitions" section of the documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#List-Transitions

Answer (score 0):

If you add the deletedItem class to the clicked item first:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr')[index].classList.add('deleted_animation')
```

(I'm sure you could find a better way to select the clicked item)

And then after that use a setTimeout to delay the action:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.array.splice(index, 1);
    this.addedId = null;
}, 500)
```

You will achieve most of this. Depending on the indexes won't be great though since you might quickly click the remove button multiple times. So maybe after the button is clicked you can block the click action on all of the buttons and then add it back after the item is spliced out.